# How to script a bookmark-jump call

Tags: commands, interactive, bookmarks, call-interactively

I am trying to write a function which will perform a bookmark-jump but then reset the the bookmark line to the top of the screen. So far I have:

```
  (defun foo ()
    (interactive)
    (bookmark-jump)
    (evil-scroll-line-to-top nil)
    )

  (define-key evil-normal-state-map [f9] 'foo)
```

But hitting F9 gives this message. What am I doing wrong please?

[image]

Comment: `bookmark-jump` needs a `bookmark` as argument: do `C-h f bookmark-jump RET` to see its doc string.

Comment: In which case how come I can do `M-x bookmark-jump<Enter>`?

Comment: When I do `M-x bookmark-jump` it asks me for a bookmark to jump to.

Comment: Agreed. Which is why I don't get that calling the same command from script doesn't do the same thing. I would expect calling it from script to prompt me for a bookmark also.

Comment: You need to use `call-interactively` for that as @Drew points out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command needs to call `bookmark-jump` interactively, so it can prompt for the bookmark you want to jump to.  It requires a bookmark, to know where to take you.

```lisp
(defun foo ()
    (interactive)
    (call-interactively #'bookmark-jump)
    (message "XXXXXXXXXX"))
```

On the other hand, if you always want `foo` to jump to the same bookmark, and you know which bookmark that is:

```lisp
(defun foo ()
    (interactive)
    (bookmark-jump "my-bookmark-name")
    (message "XXXXXXXXXX"))
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I need. I notice an issue though, which occurs calling the first foo function above and when doing `M-x bookmark-jump`: if the bookmark is in a buffer other than the visible one, the bookmarked buffer gets focus but the cursor position is unchanged - in other words the jump visits the correct buffer but not the correct location.

Comment: You comment suggests a bug somewhere. Is this Emacs bug #[44185](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=44185)? Does your recipe's "Start Emacs" use `emacs -Q`? If not, provide a recipe to repro the problem that does start with that (i.e., no init file).

Comment: Yes, I submitted that bug report. Apologies if the recipe did not start with with emacs -Q,  it should have.